# How to create or Add EULA in React Native ios APP?

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, app-store-connect

I am going to submit my first app on app store.My app rejected due this Require that users agree to terms (EULA) and these terms must make it clear that there is no tolerance for objectionable content or abusive users.My question is how to add EULA in react native ios App?

Answer (score 0):

The question might be solved but for reference as of 2023:

As it states in the review:

> If you are using the standard Apple Terms of Use (EULA), you will need to include a link to the Terms of Use in your App Description. If you are using a custom EULA, add it in App Store Connect.

You can edit your Apps description upon putting your app up for a review

If you want to opt for a custom EULA follow the docs here: 
https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-app-information/provide-a-custom-license-agreement